# iOS9: ContactFramework: Query number of contacts

Tags: swift, ios9, cncontactstore

How can I query the number of contacts in the iOS9 adressbook? In ABAdressbook, there was ABAddressBookGetPersonCount. Is there an equivalent in iOS9?

I'm importing the contacts into my app, going through all the groups, etc. What I want is to display a progress indicator for the import. For this I need the total count of contacts.

Comment: No. Iterate over them, count them and then do the heavy work